# create a matrix given a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

[image][image]I have the following vector in R :

```
p = c(1/4,1/8,1/6,1/16,3/16,1/12,1/8);p
```

which has length 7.

I want to create a matrix that will be N times N, where here N=7 but the the entries to be with metropolis Hastings algorithm.
As the picture suggests:
So $r(x,y)=1/7$

and $p(x,y) =r(x,y) \min(\frac{\pi(y)}{\pi(x)},1)$

For example the $$p(1,2) = 1/7 \cdot \min(\frac{1/8}{1/4},1) =1/14$$

$$p(1,3) = 1/7 \cdot \min(\frac{1/6}{1/4},1) =2/21$$ apart from the entry $p(1,1) = 1-\sum_{i=2}^{j=7}p(i,j).$
This sum will be in all the diagonal entries.

```
r = 1/7
r*min(p[2]/p[1],1)
```

Any help ?

Comment: I guess you can see that latex does not work in your post. Please try to better format your question.

Comment: how I write latex here ?

Comment: You cannot. But you can insert external images with links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're going for (e.g., why does 'P(2,1) = 1/7' ?), but figured I'd give it a try. Does this help?

```
f <- function(x) p[-x]/p[x]*(1/7)
M <- t(sapply(1:7,f))
M[1,1] <- 0
```

Output:

```
> M

          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.0952381 0.03571429 0.10714286 0.04761905 0.07142857
[2,] 0.2857143 0.1904762 0.07142857 0.21428571 0.09523810 0.14285714
[3,] 0.2142857 0.1071429 0.05357143 0.16071429 0.07142857 0.10714286
[4,] 0.5714286 0.2857143 0.38095238 0.42857143 0.19047619 0.28571429
[5,] 0.1904762 0.0952381 0.12698413 0.04761905 0.06349206 0.09523810
[6,] 0.4285714 0.2142857 0.28571429 0.10714286 0.32142857 0.21428571
[7,] 0.2857143 0.1428571 0.19047619 0.07142857 0.21428571 0.09523810
```

Comment: P(2,1)= 1/7*min(1/4/1/8,1) which is 1/7.The diagonal entries are 1-sum(all the values in the row)

Comment: The function must be 1/7*min(p[1]/p[2],1) for p(2,1) entry

Comment: I uploaded a new photo for better understanding